# Positioning of pictures in Beamer

Tags: beamer, positioning, includegraphics

I would like to position a picture where the red rectangle is:

[image]

I have heard of the package textpos but I could not make it work so far.
It would be very kind of you to help me (with a concrete line of code). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide some code to work with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

And, within "frame":

```
\begin{frame}{DAS Argument}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

        \node[opacity=0.1,xshift=0cm,yshift=-0cm,at=(current page.center)] {
        \includegraphics[height=2cm,scale=1]{example-image-golden}
        };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
```

Adjust xshift/yshift and/or height accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for